# spring-boot-starter can not find beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a autoconfiguration class SFConfig that defines the following beans

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(value = SalesforceClientConfig.class)
SalesforceClient sfClient(SalesforceClientConfig sfConfig){
    return SalesforceRestClient.from(sfConfig);
}

@Bean
//@ConditionalOnBean(value = Authentication.class)
SalesforceClientConfig sfClientConfig(Authentication sfAuthentication){
    return DefaultSalesforceClientConfig.builder()
                                        .authentication(sfAuthentication)
                                        .mapper(mapper())
                                        .build();
}
```

As evident sfClient bean should be created because SalesforceClientConfig is created. But it throws an exception:

```
 Bean method 'sfClient' in 'SFConfig' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.ondeck.salesforceclient.SalesforceClientConfig; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans
```

This weird because this is an autoconfiguration class and it should find that bean. Any thoughts?

Here is how I have defined my autoconfiguration classes in the file:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
```

com.ondeck.letter.config.SpringJpaDBConfig,\
com.ondeck.letter.config.SFConfig

Comment: I tried something and it worked but that is super weird and I can not believe spring would do something like that: I changed the order of the method in the class and it worked. Is that normal

Answer (score 0):

According to [Annotation Type ConditionalOnBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html), it's recommended to use `@ConditionalOnBean` annotation in the auto configuration classes annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

So probably you have not properly defined auto configuration class.

Comment: i don't think that is an issue. See my comment when i switch the order in which the methods are defined it works.

Comment: Yes, probably it's problem with Java compiler, when you dont have proper auto connfiguration.

Comment: i am not sure what do you mean by proper autoconfiguration. I have spring.factories file and that has the configuration file. Do you mind elaborating on what you mean by "not proper"